# scripting a "manual" apt-get install of kept back packages

Tags: apt, upgrade, bash

**TL;DR:** is there a way to "automatically" install any kept back packages? I know that `apt-get dist-upgrade` is too blunt of an instrument.

**Details...**

I have a bash script that runs (periodically) to keep Ubuntu Desktop VMs in a consistent state.

It does the usual `apt-get update` ... `apt-get upgrade` routine. Of course, there are the periodic kept-back packages.

I have addressed this up to now by adding the kept back packages to a manual list of `apt-get install <whatever was kept back>`. I have started exploring a way to make this less manual.

About the time I found myself (seriously) pondering how to refactor `sudo apt-get -V upgrade | grep '=>' | grep -Ei '([A-Z]+(-)?)+' -o | sed 'N;s/\n/ /;'` for readability, it occurred to me that perhaps there is a better way. (yes... I hadn't quite fixed the bugs in that line either)

The horribleness above was an attempt to pull out the (unversioned) kept back package names in order to pass them dynamically to `apt-get install`.

So, *is* there a better way to identify the kept back packages and install them via `apt-get install`?

Comment: well... I still hope that there *is* a better way, but [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed] showed me how to get sed doing what I want in my ugly line above:
`sudo apt-get -V upgrade | grep '=>' | grep -Ei '([A-Z]+(-)?)+' -o | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'` isolates the names of the kept-back packages

Answer (score 2):

I did more noodling on the problem (and learned lots more about sed along the way). I'm not convinced that this is the *best* way, but it is a way. If anyone has a better way to do this, **please** answer, and I'll happily take your answeer.

`sudo apt-get upgrade -s | sed -n '/back:/,/upgraded./p' | sed '1d;$d'`

The `-s` option of `apt-get upgrade` indicates a dry-run rather than an actual install. I pipe the dry-run output text to sed, where magic happens. In sed, `-n` makes it quiet, so only what I tell it to print actually prints. The *what* to print is defined by a starting and ending regex. *Start* with a line matching "back:", and *end* with a line matching "upgraded.". The sed syntax was tricky at first... [linuxcommando](http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2008/03/using-sed-to-extract-lines-in-text-file.html) helped me grok the basic range-of-lines selection. That last `p` is telling sed "ok... print now".

The output of the first sed is something like:

> The following packages were kept back:
>
> thing1 thing2 newthing3
>
> 42 upgraded, 7 newly installed 1 to remove, and 3 not upgraded.

I pipe *that* to another, simpler sed that drops the first and last lines (`1d;$d`). Note, there are ways to do line offset magic in the first sed, but I felt that made the single sed too confusing. I'm ok using a second sed, which leaves just:

> thing1 thing2 newthing3

And those are the kept-back packages to manually install.

```
kept_back_packages=$(sudo apt-get upgrade -s | sed -n '/back:/,/upgraded./p' | sed '1d;$d')
sudo apt-get install $kept_back_packages -y
```

(the `-y` is just an assume-yes for scripted apt-get).

#### Note:

when there are no kept back packages, this handles it all gracefully and does nothing. An empty string gets passed to apt-get install, and that's ok.

Comment: Note: use `yes n | sudo apt-get upgrade` to simply say "no" to initiating the upgrade. Much faster than a full dry run